# Can't get value of a Select HTML using Jquery when id has non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: jquery, html

In my jquery experience I didn't have any encounters of using other characters aside from alphanumeric(of course id and class selectors are included) using in string selectors, now in my current project id's contains [] and put it literally on my selectors and it doesn't work at all.

```
<select name="pdcompany[0]" id="pdcompany[0]">
        <option value="0">
            Please select
        </option>
```

I read already about the rules in creating selectors http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ from the docs and followed them and still doesn't' work. what i went wrong?

```
    selector = "#pdcompany\\[0\\] > option:selected";
    alert('Selector: ' + selector);
    alert($(selector).text());
```

here is my fiddle for your disposal http://jsfiddle.net/laupkram/Fd42a/

**UPDATE**

already fixed some mistakes in selectors... missing `#`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the " > option:selected" since .val already gives you that. Just do:

```
selector = "#pdcompany\\[0\\]";
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `$('[id="pdcompany[0]"]').text();`. Make use of quotation marks and the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/Fd42a/6/)

Translated for your use:

```
$('[id="pdcompany[0]"] option:selected')...
```

BTW, unless your select is a `multiple`, there's no need to use `option:selected`. `.val()` will work quite nicely.